# new comment notification in teaser mode in links

Tags: 7, comments

Yesterday I saw "2 new comment" in teaser view in one of news in my Drupal-based website. when I click on news and read it and return to news list, the notification was gone. Now I want know where Drupal create this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `history` db table in Drupal: *"A record of which users have read which nodes."*
It contains last time when user viewed a node. This data allows to show new content and new comments to user.
Comment module uses it to determine how many new comments appeared while user was not on the node page in [`comment_num_new()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!comment!comment.module/function/comment_num_new/7) function.
Link “2 new comments” was added by [this code](http://drupalcode.org/project/drupal.git/blob/30d1e719aa5e9a9ad66514078ca3b0975ddadc9c:/modules/comment/comment.module#l637) in `comment.module` file through `hook_node_view()` hook:

```
  // Show a link to the first new comment.
  if ($new = comment_num_new($node->nid)) {
    $links['comment-new-comments'] = array(
      'title' => format_plural($new, '1 new comment', '@count new comments'),
      'href' => "node/$node->nid",
      'query' => comment_new_page_count($node->comment_count, $new, $node),
      'attributes' => array('title' => t('Jump to the first new comment of this posting.')),
      'fragment' => 'new',
      'html' => TRUE,
    );
  }
```